# how to get all the records added for 1 last minute

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to SQL. 
I am using SQL Server 2008.
I am trying to get records from table added for within last 1 minute. 
actually I have SP which get called after every 1 minute 60sec, and I do not have any column which saved modified date, so I have to select all the rows added within minute of time interval.

It may happen no rows added or N number of rows added within last minute, so i need to get all of them added with 1 minute of timer interval, since SP will get fired after every 1 Min.

Comment: If you have no column that stores the creation and/or modification time there is no way to retrieve the information you want. And you should add which DBMS you are using. Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: sql server 2008.. so in general we can not retrieve last added record within specific time.

Comment: Consider to change your table to add a new column `creationDate` and/or `modificationDate` of type `DATETIME` and put default value as `GETDATE` it is a function which returns the current datetime value. So after this you can query your table with one of this columns (the one you choose or both)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all records in a table that have been inserted in the last minute, you would need a date field on your table that either has a DEFAULT GETDATE() constraint, or insert the date manually when you insert the record.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyDateColumn >= DATEADD(mi, -1, GETDATE())
```

And the create a column with the default on an existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD MyDateColumn DATETIME2 NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

You might be able to get table / row metadata from the sys or INFORMATION_SCHEMA schemas, but I really wouldn't recommend it.

Saying that, maybe your application / database is suitable for SQL Server Auditing?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx

**UPDATE**

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but it might be a viable solution. I wrote a cursor to create and apply audit triggers to all the tables in a database a while back. The triggers are set up to log to a separate table (which is currently hard coded). You can modify this for your needs, but I've included all the relevant code below. I imagine you will need to remove the UserId and its constraints:

```
-- Stores the types of audit entries for the "Logs" table, such as "RECORD CREATED", "RECORD MODIFIED", "RECORD DELETED" and other, miscellaneous log types
CREATE TABLE dbo.LogTypes (
    LogTypeID                   INT             NOT NULL    IDENTITY    PRIMARY KEY,
    [Description]               VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL    UNIQUE
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.[Logs] (
    LogID                       INT             NOT NULL    IDENTITY    PRIMARY KEY,
    LogTypeID                   INT             NOT NULL    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES LogTypes(LogTypeID),
    UserID                      INT             NOT NULL    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(UserID), -- User that created this log entry.
    SysObjectID                 INT, -- The ID of the table in sysobjects (if this is a CRUD insert from a trigger)
    Details                     VARCHAR(1000),
    DateCreated                 DATETIME        NOT NULL    DEFAULT GETDATE()
)

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Log types
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SET IDENTITY_INSERT LogTypes ON

INSERT INTO LogTypes (LogTypeID, [Description])
VALUES(1, 'Record Insert')
INSERT INTO LogTypes (LogTypeID, [Description])
VALUES(2, 'Record Update')
INSERT INTO LogTypes (LogTypeID, [Description])
VALUES(3, 'Record Deletion')
INSERT INTO LogTypes (LogTypeID, [Description])
VALUES(4, 'User logged in')
INSERT INTO LogTypes (LogTypeID, [Description])
VALUES(5, 'User logged out')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT LogTypes OFF
```

Cursor code (run once):

```
DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(500), @instruction VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE curTables CURSOR READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD FOR
 SELECT TABLE_NAME
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 WHERE TABLE_NAME <> 'Logs'

OPEN curTables

FETCH NEXT FROM curTables INTO @table_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        -- Drop any existing trigger
        SET @instruction = 'IF OBJECT_ID (''tr_' + @table_name + '_Audit'',''TR'') IS NOT NULL DROP TRIGGER tr_' + @table_name + '_Audit;'
        exec sp_sqlexec @instruction

        -- Create the new trigger
        SET @instruction = 'CREATE TRIGGER tr_' + @table_name + '_Audit
        ON ' + @table_name + '
            AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
        AS
            SET NOCOUNT ON

            DECLARE @LogTypeID INT, @SystemUserID INT, @SysObjectID INT, @TableName VARCHAR(500)

            SET @SystemUserID   = 1 -- System account
            SET @TableName      = ''' + @table_name + '''

            IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Inserted) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Deleted)
                SET @LogTypeID = 2 -- Update
            ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Inserted)
                SET @LogTypeID = 1 -- Insertion
            ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Deleted)
                SET @LogTypeID = 3 -- Deletion

            SET @LogTypeID = ISNULL(@LogTypeID, 0)

            IF @LogTypeID > 0
                BEGIN
                    -- Only log if successful
                    SELECT
                        @SysObjectID = id
                    FROM sysobjects (nolock)
                    where [name]    = @TableName
                    AND [type]      = ''U''

                    INSERT INTO [Logs] (LogTypeID, UserID, SysObjectID, Details, DateCreated)
                    VALUES(@LogTypeID, @SystemUserID, @SysObjectID, NULL, GETDATE())
                END'
        exec sp_sqlexec @instruction

        FETCH NEXT FROM curTables INTO @table_name
    END

CLOSE curTables
DEALLOCATE curTables
```

Every table in your database will now log all INSERTs, UPDATEs and DELETEs to the Log table. However, be aware that adding triggers to your tables increases I/O and memory usage, subsequently decreasing performance. It may not be a massive problem for you, though.

Comment: however i can not used solution but this is the only solution to get data it need modified date column in table which i do not have and i can not add any column(no permission) so i am thinking to use some other logic.

Comment: I have previously used triggers to audit tables - inserting records into a Log table every time the record has been added, modified or deleted. I wrote a cursor to apply triggers to each table in my database. I've edited my post to include the sproc incase it's handy.